# How to include a count with sub query in Prisma?

Tags: next.js, prisma

```
const user = await prisma.users.findFirst({
  where: {
    id: +userid,
  },
  include: {
    _count: {
      select: {
        licenses: true,
        orders: true,
      },
    },
  },
});
```

I have tables related to a user "tokens" "orders". I also have a "payments" table associated with "orders" by order id.

Is there a way to get a Count of all payments a user has made on their orders?

Like User > Order > Payment

So when I get my return back it would be:

```
_count: { licenses: 10, orders: 12, payments: 12 }
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible yet, you might need to use Raw Queries: https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/raw-database-access

Answer (score 0):

If you replace the `include` in your request by a `select`, you can get the payment count for this user:

```
const user = await p.users.findFirst({
    where: {
      id: +userId,
    },
    select: {
      id: true,
      orders: {
        select: {
          _count: {
            select: { payments: true },
          }
        }
      },
      _count: {
        select: {
          licenses: true,
          orders: true,
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

Note that each `_count` part is a sub query made by prisma, so if you need to do the same request for a group of users you might face performance issues.